# SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

Tags: php, phpmailer, sparkpost

I'm getting this errors while trying to send an email via PHPMailer:

> **Deprecated:** preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in **/home/u722941258/public_html/old/account/access/mailer/class.phpmailer.php**  on line 1727
>
> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
>
> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

---

The PHP Code:

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
    {
        require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;    
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.sparkpostmail.com';  
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
        $mail->Username = 'USER';                 
        $mail->Password = 'SECRET';                           
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->SetFrom('admin@email.sosgram.ga','Verificación de Cuentas');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("soporte@email.sosgram.ga","Soporte SOSgram");
        $mail->Subject  = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
    }
```

Any solution?

---

---

Hosting: http://hostinger.es

SMTP: http://sparkpost.com

Comment: you can try another port number as well another SMTPSecure *like 456 , ssl*.

Comment: @Soni Vimal I've already tried this, and doesn't work. SparkPost just uses TLS ports 587 and 2525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like outgoing port is blocked in your server. You can try using port `2525`.

If that's also blocked, you can either open one of those two or use [php client library](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost/) which uses port 80/443 and it's very unlikely for those ports to be blocked;